# Two problems with Address Sanitizer

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

In a hobby project I use the address sanitizer (-fsanitize=address)
and g++-6 (Homebrew GCC 6.3.0_1) 6.3.0.

I got an error that I do not understand, which is:

`==94266==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_globals.cc:146 "((AddrIsAlignedByGranularity(g->size_with_redzone))) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    #0 0x10b60cd3d in __asan::AsanCheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) (libasan.3.dylib+0x5dd3d)
    #1 0x10b612be3 in __sanitizer::CheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) (libasan.3.dylib+0x63be3)`

After playing around for a while, I noticed that I am using regex in two different classes, and if I remove either one of them, the problem disappears. I want to understand why and what I can do about that.

So, my next attempt is to build a minimum example of the problem, and I came up with the following:

```
// a.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void a(const std::string &s)
{
    regex re_a("foo (.+)");
    smatch pieces;

    if (regex_match(s, pieces, re_a))
    {
        cout << "foo with " << pieces[1].str() << endl;
    }
}

// m.cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>

void a(const std::string &s);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::regex re("123");

    a("foo test 123");
}
```

If I compile with "g++-6 -fsanitize=address a.cpp m.cpp" and then run "./a.out", the program hangs forever, while "g++-6 a.cpp m.cpp" followed by "./a.out" just works as expected.

This is not the exactly what I wanted to demonstrate here (as I do not get the AddressSanitizer CHECK failed error), but the problems could be related?

I do see a few of these as well, just to be complete:
`ld: warning: direct access in function '__GLOBAL__sub_D_00099_0_a.cpp' from file '/var/folders/lq/t18hc5bn0c5bxf7h7nn609f40000gp/T//ccTC4rgj.o' to global weak symbol 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>::lookup_collatename<char const*>(char const*, char const*) const::__collatenames' from file '/var/folders/lq/t18hc5bn0c5bxf7h7nn609f40000gp/T//ccTC4rgj.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.`

edit: forgot to mention one detail I also noticed. If I comment out the regex var 're' in m.cpp, the problem also disappears completely.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Tip: If you [symbolize the reports](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#symbolizing-the-reports) from asan, they become somewhat easier to read.

Comment: Asan pads global variables with chunks of metadata (called "redzones") which are used by Asan runtime at startup to traverse the list of globals. My guess is that in your case there's a a name clash which causes Asan to pick address of some static variable from unsanitized code which misses metadata. For proper diagnosis I suggest to file issue in [Asan tracker](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/).

Comment: Thanks @yugr, I've reported [an issue](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/801) there.